# The address of the Web Page is wrong after login

Tags: javascript, jquery, webaddress

I am using asp.net and i am trying to login from the fancy box. I have code sample like this :

```
          function (LoginResponse) {
                      $.each(LoginResponse, function () {
                          if (this["IsLogin"] == "true") {
                              window.location.reload(true);
                              window.location.href = "Account/MyProfile.aspx";
                          }
                          else {
                              jAlert('Warning!', 'Invalid login Credintials', 'Please enter valid Username and Password..', 'yellow');
                          }
                          clear_form_elements('#UserLoginSection'); //Clears the element of the form
                      });
                  }
                    );
```

Some time it goes well with this address  "Account/MyProfile.aspx" But some time The Address wrong and in the address bar something like this come again and again "Account/Account/MyProfile.aspx" There  should not be Double Account meaning "Account/MyProfile.aspx" should be there. and I have tried to remove Account in the javascript function above But some time it works well but some time it does not. What i have to do please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to land the user after login on "MyProfile.aspx" then use window.location.href or if you want them on same page then only use location.reload(true). No need to use both at same time.

Comment: I have commented either of them and made a test but still the same result. I have commented this :`// window.location.reload(true);` and made test but the result is same. and again made a test by commenting `//window.location.href = "Account/MyProfile.aspx";` and remove the comment of the ` window.location.reload(true);` but still i have same result

Comment: Please add "/" in start of url. Like window.location.href = "/Account/MyProfile.aspx";

Answer (score 0):

Setting location.href to a different URL should already reload the page. Use either reload or location.href, not both.